# Possible locations for shellcode in a buffer-overflow exploit

Tags: buffer-overflow, shellcode

I am learning about buffer overflows in ethical hacking and I am aware of exploits where the shellcode is either placed in the stack, or stored as an environment variable when the buffer size is too small or when it's non-executable. But what if the buffer size is too small and the environment variable is not accessible or off-limits? In that case, where can I place my shellcode?

I would appreciate any help as I've been researching about this for a long time and I couldn't find articles that would help me with this issue.

Comment: In another known buffer. The buffer you overflow don't has to have the shellcode. Look at the source and find an entry.

Comment: Yeah I get what you're saying, but what kind of entries can I exploit? Can you give an example? In my source, there's no buffer actually but whatever input I give in the command line, the target binary gives a segmentation fault.